# Auto sync sharepoint with 'my documents'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is this possible to sync sharepoint documents automatically as soon as system finds any internet connection?

There is a sharepoint site which gets updated every week with the latest version of a document. I would like to have document library folder on my machine which can automatically be synchronized when there is a latest version of a document available. So i don't have to manually sync it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In 2010 you can use the SharePoint Workspace application to sync content from SharePoint locally.  In 2013, you can use SkyDrive to sync your SkyDrive content from SharePoint locally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is SharePoint Workspace or SkyDrive free to install on client machines?

Comment: The SkyDrive Pro client comes with Office 2013, or is available as a standalone download (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39050).  You cannot install the standalone with Office 2013 (they will conflict).  SharePoint Workspace is included with the Professional Plus edition of Office 2010.

Comment: can we use skydrive on ipad (android OS) to access sharepoint 2010 or 2013 documents?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are here:
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Set-up-your-computer-to-sync-SharePoint-files-or-OneDrive-for-Business-files-when-you-re-not-using-Office-365-59b1de2b-519e-4d3a-8f45-51647cf291cd

Alternatively, a 3rd party product is here: http://spsync.net/